# Не находит невидимую ячейку в collectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

В моем `ViewController` есть `collectionView` с двумя ячейками, в одной находится карта, а во второй описание маршрута(таймер, пройденное расстояние и средний темп передвижения), а так же кнопка `pauseButton` (во `ViewController`). `Cell` имеют размер экрана, т.е. они скролятся, и на экране видно только одну ячейку.

По нажатию на кнопку `pauseButtonAction` я хочу, чтобы в обоих ячейках выполнялось `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`. Он выполняется только в той ячейке, которая видна на экране, вторую он не видит.

`tableView.cellForItem(indexPath)` не помогает, `tableView.visibleCells` так же очевидно не работает.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let runCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RunCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RunCollectionViewCell
        let mapCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MapCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MapCollectionViewCell
        if indexPath.item == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 {
             return mapCell
        } else {
             return runCell
        }
    ///////////////
    @IBAction func pauseButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let indexPathRunCell = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)
        let indexPathMapCell = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        if let mapCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPathMapCell) as? MapCollectionViewCell {
            print("MapCell найдена")
            mapCell.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            print ("mapCell не найдена")
        }
        if let runCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPathRunCell) as? RunCollectionViewCell {
            print("runCell найдена")
            runCell.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            runCell.didTapPauseButton()
        } else {
            print("runCell не найдена")

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ячейки UITableView / UICollectionView переиспользуются, поэтому слегка некорректно в самих ячейках хранить какие-то данные/выполнять логику и прочее, и затем пытаться искать нужную ячейку чтобы с ней что-то сделать.

Нужно вынести Ваши `locationManager'ы` для начала во ViewController и при необходимости приостановить обращаться напрямую к ним, а в `collectionView (_:cellForItemAt:)` передавать их в ячейку.

Comment: у меня две ячейки размером на полный экран, ViewController передает данные только в ту ячейку, которая в данный момент на экране. Пример: